Saving a Blob via browser/web
There is an API that returns a string to me in the response body that is a PDF (there is a string inside RAW response).
I want to save this PDF via the web/browser (not Android/iOS).
I assembled the sequence, but I can't send the BLOB to be downloaded by the browser.
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future salvaStringEmPDF(String conteudo, String nomeArquivo) async {
  debugPrint('Entrou na action');

  var url =
      "https://api.XXXX.com.br/v2/documentos/191XXXX993/pdf?incluir_fonte_pdf=true";


  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    "Accept": "application/pdf",
    "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXX"
  });

  debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("API returned 200");
    print(response.body);

    List<int> bytes = response.bodyBytes;

    final blob = html.Blob([bytes], 'application/pdf');
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    final anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
      ..href = url
      ..style.display = 'none'
      ..download = 'pdf.pdf';

    html.document.body.children.add(anchor);
    
  } else {
    print("Api ERROR");
  }
}

I was trying to use WriteAsByte but it comes from the dart.io library and this library is only for Android and iOS - it is not suitable for the web. The documents I read talk about BLOB.
As a final objective, I want to take the string that came from that API (which is a PDF file) and send it to the browser for the user to download.
If you have another approach to sending the return from this API to the browser to save as a PDF, I also accept it.
Please, can you help me?

I understood your reasoning. Yeah I agree. So much so that you can see in my code that I get the result in bytes.
But my question is precisely when it comes to taking this return and redirecting it to the browser as a PDF using Flutter. Can you help me with a piece of code? Just highlighting that because it's web, I can't use the dart.io library.
